# ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: 'AnsibleLoader' object has no attribute 'get_single_data'

Tags: ansible

When I repeat the command "ansible-playbook single.yml" to set the environment. 
I got an ansible error "ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: 'AnsibleLoader' object has no attribute 'get_single_data' to see the full traceback, use -vvv".

[root@localhost data]# ansible --version

ansible 2.8.4
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]

I am not familiar with ansible, and I don't know why it worked before, but now I get an error, and I don't know how to solve it. It is my first time to ask questions here. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hi X.Joy, welcome to SO. Can you show your playbook (or at least the task causing the error) and provide a more detailed error as advised in your output (option `-vvv`) ? Please don't add those information in comments: edit your question. While you are at it, read the helpers at screen right and format your code/command line output correctly. And more globally, take some time to learn how SO functions by visiting the help section, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you please share "single.yml"  here